Use wget to retrieve Supplemental Data from Science dot org
I'm building a pipeline in Snakemake to analyse some data. One of the data files I'm using is provided as supplemental data as part of this publication. The paper is behind a paywall, but I've accessed it through my institution. The supplemental data is available publically, as I can insert this URL into my browser to download it.
When I use wget targetting that URL however, I receive a 403 Forbidden error. I saw that this question raises a similar issue, but trying a few referer values doesn't seem to fix anything. Developer mode on Firefox doesn't seem to give me any more information on the download process.
How can I integrate this download into my pipeline?

This server response is a hint that the server's administrators do not want you to use it as part of an automated pipeline. Download the data once and host it locally.
If you want to use wget anyway, the other most common header used for such restrictions is User-Agent, where wget identifies itself as wget. Often a generic "Mozilla/4.0" is enough to bypass such blocks, sometimes you have to start from a real browser's User-Agent (and trim it down).
The general approach would be to copy the browser's request as-is (DevTools offers an option to "copy as curl command"), verify that it still works from CLI, and remove the custom headers one by one until the server's response changes to "Forbidden".

I'm hoping to have the pipeline be exportable and shareable with biologists, so having everything contained in the pipeline is a big plus. I'll look into the user agent tag :)

@Whitehot why not ask permission from the authors to mirror this file somewhere more amenable to such usage? You could host it on GitHub or an S3 bucket or something (or ask the authors if they'd be willing to do so)
